# Error "Property 'mock' does not exist on"... when running gulp client tests

Tags: angularjs, gulp, karma-jasmine, angular-fullstack

So im trying to run some tests in my project and this is the error I get when I run `gulp test:client`.

I couldn't find much information about it and I really don't get why this is happening. My project is based on the Angular Fullstack Generator 4.2.0.

Node version is 6.10 and npm 4.5.

Any hint is really appreciated.

Thanks!

```
pablos-mbp:widget pablo$ gulp test:client
    31 08 2017 11:02:14.747:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket xrwLxHjkTkNLJhc3AAAA with id 5085667
31 08 2017 11:02:14.747:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 5085667) captured in 1.392 secs
31 08 2017 11:02:14.753:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]:

31 08 2017 11:02:14.755:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
31 08 2017 11:02:14.758:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad /
31 08 2017 11:02:14.758:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.759:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.760:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
31 08 2017 11:02:14.760:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.761:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.761:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/spec.js?7a69f03490a6f80f910cff86fc37abc9ee7cd0f6 /
31 08 2017 11:02:14.762:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/spec.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.762:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7a813cc290d592e664331c573a1a796192cdd1ad /
31 08 2017 11:02:14.762:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.762:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/spec.js
31 08 2017 11:02:14.819:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js

  Component: MainComponent
    ✓ should attach a list of things to the controller

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.003 secs / 0.035 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS

31 08 2017 11:02:15.022:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
31 08 2017 11:02:15.022:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
31 08 2017 11:02:15.029:DEBUG [coverage]: Writing coverage to /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/coverage/client
31 08 2017 11:02:15.114:DEBUG [coverage]: Writing coverage to /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/coverage
31 08 2017 11:02:15.126:DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 0
31 08 2017 11:02:15.126:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/n5/31jf7x153xx_b_yqskjlj5m00000gn/T/karma-5085667
31 08 2017 11:02:15.135:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
[11:02:15] Finished 'test:client' after 6.12 s
pablos-mbp:widget pablo$ [default] /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/client/app/main/main.component.spec.ts:9:22
    Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'.
[default] /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/client/app/main/main.component.spec.ts:10:22
    Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'.
[default] /Users/pablo/workspace/widget/client/app/main/main.component.spec.ts:18:14
    Cannot find name 'inject'.
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the typings for the angular-mocks library

Comment: I tryied running `npm install --save @types/angular-mocks@1.5.11` but still have that annoying error.